# Simple insert-erase-insert on std::deque<char> gives strange result

Tags: c++, stl, deque

Here is a simple program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <string.h>

std :: deque <char> d;

int main ()
{
    const char * X = "abcdefg";

    d .insert (d .end (), X, X + strlen (X));

    d .erase  (d .begin (), d .begin () + 4);

    d .insert (d .end (), X, X + strlen (X));

    std :: cout .write (& d [0], d .size ());
}
```

I expected the output to be "efgabcdefg", the actual output, in hex, is

```
65 66 67 00  00 00 00 C9  0B 02
```

which is "efg???????"

What has gone wrong?

Comment: what's with all the spaces?

Comment: I use whitespace generously. I use consecutive nonblank lines only for long argument lists or when short statements form a logical block (e.g. `start += used;\nsize -= used;`

Comment: Not to sweat the small stuff, but almost 99,9% of your fellow programmers use no spaces around the address/dereference operators `.`, `->`, `::`, `*`, `&`, and `[]`. Are you allowd to use this at work? (at least it's not as bad as having no spaces anywhere, as in the obfuscated C code contests)

Comment: +1 BTW, for reminding me that there is also an `ostream::write` member :-)

Comment: I like whitespace. Try it sometime.

Comment: [Linus won't let me](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your output is that `deque` has no guarantee that its elements are stored contiguously, and in fact will almost certainly not be. This means that when you take the address of the first element and a size you may not be accessing all the elements of the `deque`.

You have multiple approachs to solve your problem.

The simplest seems to be to use `string` instead of `deque`. Then printing becomes trivial, and the cut-then-append is also trivial.

You could also use for example an `ostream_iterator` to print out the contents of the `deque`.

Finally you could use `vector` instead as it *is* guranteed to store its elements contiguously.

Answer (score 6):

`std::deque` doesn't store its elements contiguosly in memory. If you need that, use `std::vector`. In other words, `&d[0]` is not a start of a buffer of length `d.size()` which you could pass to `write()`.

Comment: Very succinct.  +1.  As an alernative to `write()`, [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ostream_iterator/) can remove that "contiguous" requirement.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you cannot do pointer arithmetic on
the results of `&deque<>::operator[]`, and expect anything
reasonable.  This is guaranteed for `std::vector`, but that is
a special case.

The idiomatic way of doing what you seem to want is:

```
std::copy( d.begin(), d.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>( std::cout ) );
```

And that would be true, regardless of the type of `d`.

But why not use `std::vector<char>`.  For cheap to copy types
like `char`, it's probably faster than `deque` anyway, even for
the `erase` at the beginning.